# How to check if 'TF Get' command returned 'All files are up to date.'?

Tags: batch-file, tfs, errorlevel

I'm writing a script that uses **'tf get'** command line, and **than run a 'heavy duty' script** if and only if the get command did changed something.

I looked at tf get exit codes, and it doesn't seem to return the relevant information.

I was thinking of using **findstr** to do the trick, but before doing so:

is there other more 'easy / elegant' way to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing changed after running the `tf get` command, the only information it
will return is
[image]

If you want to capture this info, findstr is indeed a good workaround to do the trick.